# NLP -Negative Sampling

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I got[image] Error from this code. Can Anyone help me? This is Word2Vec Algorithm

```
def negative_sampling(self, center_word, context_word):
        # use this variable to control the number of negative samples for every positive sample
        num_neg_samples_per_center = self.num_neg_samples_per_center
        batch_size = center_word.shape[0]

        # generate positive pairs
        center_word_embeddings = self.center_embeddings(center_word) # batch_size, embedding_dim
        context_word_embeddings = self.context_embeddings(context_word) # batch_size, embedding_dim
        pos_pairs = torch.cat((center_word_embeddings.unsqueeze(1), context_word_embeddings.unsqueeze(1)), dim=1) # batch_size, 2, embedding_dim

        # generate negative samples
        neg_samples = []
        while len(neg_samples) < batch_size * num_neg_samples_per_center:
            # sample words randomly based on their frequency count
            neg_words = torch.multinomial(self.counts, num_neg_samples_per_center * batch_size, replacement=True)
            # exclude the positive words
            excluded = torch.cat((center_word.unsqueeze(1), context_word.unsqueeze(1)), dim=1)
            excluded = excluded.view(-1)
            neg_words = neg_words[~torch.isin(neg_words, excluded)]
            neg_samples += neg_words.tolist()
        neg_samples = neg_samples[:batch_size * num_neg_samples_per_center]
        neg_samples = torch.LongTensor(neg_samples).reshape(batch_size, num_neg_samples_per_center)

        # get negative sample embeddings
        neg_samples_embeddings = self.context_embeddings(neg_samples) # batch_size, num_neg_samples_per_center, embedding_dim
        neg_samples_embeddings = neg_samples_embeddings.transpose(1,2) # batch_size, embedding_dim, num_neg_samples_per_center

        # calculate loss
        pos_scores = torch.bmm(pos_pairs, self.context_embeddings.weight.T.unsqueeze(0).expand(batch_size, -1, -1)).squeeze().sigmoid().log() # batch_size
        neg_scores = torch.bmm(neg_samples_embeddings.neg(), center_word_embeddings.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze().sigmoid().logsumexp(dim=1) # batch_size
        loss = -(pos_scores + neg_scores).mean()
        return loss
```

It is NLP program and I'm stuck in Negative Sampling Code. center_word and context_word are one dimention. I'm expecting make training function work

```
run_training(
    model_type = 'neg', # defines which loss function is being used to train the model
                        # can take values 'nll' for negative log loss and 'neg' for negative sampling
    lr = 10, # defines the learning rate used for training the model
    num_neg_samples_per_center = 3, # controls the number of negative samples per center word
    checkpoint_model_path = './demo_checkpoints', # defines path to the checkpoint of the model
    final_model_path = './final_demo_model', # location to save the final model
    skip_window = 1, # size of the skip window
    vocab_size = int(1e5), # size of the vocabulary used in the experiments
    num_skips = 2, # Number of samples to be drawn from a window
    batch_size = 256, # Size of the batches in terms of number of x,y pairs used for training
    embedding_size = 4, # size of the embedding vectores
    checkpoint_step = 500, # Number of steps after which checkpoint is saved
    max_num_steps = 2001 # Maximum number of steps to train for
)
```